# xcode cant add controller to splitview controller in storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a ViewController and a storyboard. The storyboard has UISplitViewController in it. I am trying to add my ViewController to the custom class section, but its not populating and when I manually type it in it doesnt save. Here is a screenshot. What is wrong?

[image]

Comment: This will only work if your custom class is a subclass of UISplitViewController.

Comment: how do I make it a subpage of UISplitViewController ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH3-SW5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your `ViewController` in code, it probably looks like that:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
// something could be here
@end
```

You should change it to the following

```
@interface ViewController : UISplitViewController
// something could be here
@end
```

Then it will appear in that dropdown